# Spring Integration: jms.Connection.setExceptionListener()

Tags: java, jms, jboss-4.2.x, jbossmq

i have only one jms listner but multiple queues.this is the right way of implementing jms JBOSS4.2 MQ?

```
System.out.println("Lookup queue");
Queue queueForResponse = (Queue) context.lookup("/queue/ResponseProcessingQueue");
Queue queueForExcelDownload = (Queue) context.lookup("/queue/ExcelDownloadQueue");
Queue queueForWebHookResponse = (Queue) context.lookup("/queue/WebHookProcessingQueue");
Queue queueForCRMAPIResponse = (Queue) context.lookup("/queue/CRMAPIProcessingQueue");
Queue queueForUploadResponse = (Queue) context.lookup("/queue/UploadResponseQueue");

System.out.println("Start connection");
connection.start();

/* consumer message  */
System.out.println("Create consumer : ");
MessageConsumer consumerForResponse = session.createConsumer(queueForResponse);
MessageConsumer consumerForExcelDownload = session.createConsumer(queueForExcelDownload);
MessageConsumer consumerForWebHook = session.createConsumer(queueForWebHookResponse);
MessageConsumer consumerForCRMAPI = session.createConsumer(queueForCRMAPIResponse);
MessageConsumer consumerForUpload = session.createConsumer(queueForUploadResponse);



System.out.println("set message listener");
consumerForResponse.setMessageListener(new MyMessageReceiver());
consumerForExcelDownload.setMessageListener(new MyMessageReceiver());
consumerForWebHook.setMessageListener(new MyMessageReceiver());
consumerForCRMAPI.setMessageListener(new MyMessageReceiver());
consumerForUpload.setMessageListener(new MyMessageReceiver());`
```

I get the following exception

> [org.jboss.mq.Connection] Connection failure, use javax.jms.Connection.setExceptionListener() to handle this error and reconnect
>   org.jboss.mq.SpyJMSException: Exiting on IOE; - nested throwable: (java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out)

Comment: can you post versions, more logs the whole stacktrace, did you use JBoss with embedded AMQ & resources adapter & jndi names ("/queue/ResponseProcessingQueue") of queues defined in server ? how did you create connection ?

Comment: My apologies but we are using JBOSS4.2 MQ and not AMQ.

Comment: ok i have removed activemq tag and i dont see any spring-jms or jmstemplate in your code, can you confirm and remove these tags and update with jboss corresponding tags to have better answer